# In Ruby on Rails, how can I send multiple update statements to the database using the dafult db connection object?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mysql2

For performance reasons, I need to issue SQL statements (insertions and updates) directly to the database. I have no problem executing a large insert statement like:

```
@conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
inserts = "INSERT INTO clients (code, name) VALUES ('abc123', 'Alyx'), ('xyz123', 'Gordon') ...many more...\;"
@conn.execute inserts
```

However, I'm having difficulty executing a batch of updates like:

```
updates = "UPDATE clients SET name='Julia' WHERE id=1; UPDATE clients SET name='Eli' WHERE id=2; ...many more..."
@conn.execute updates
# or
@conn.update updates
```

because that gives me the general SQL syntax error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

I've tried changing the database.yml configuration file to include the MULTI_STATEMENTS flag without success:

```
flags:
- MULTI_STATEMENTS
```

The only way I managed to make this work is by getting a Mysql2 client instance, with the flag set:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(host: 'localhost', ... , flags: Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS)
client.query updates
```

but this doesn't seem like a good idea since it would lock the app together with the mysql2 gem.

Is this a problem with the mysql2 gem, ActiveRecord, or am I missing something essential?

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24226826/3366016 It seems mysql2 adapter can't handle multi-statements without setting the flag like you have.  PostgreSQL seems to be able to handle it though.  You don't want to loop over the clients, or create multiple statements I guess (not ideal)?

Comment: @user3366016 I did not see that post. Thanks! I guess my keyword searches were not as good as I thought... And no, I don't want to loop with multiple statements because that would take too long on hundreds of thousands of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found there was no reason to keep using ActiveRecord since I wasn't making use of it so I decided to stick with `Mysql2::Client`.

Just make sure that `flags: Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS` is set and remember to clear the results from any previous commands before issuing another one:

```
while client.next_result
end
```

Also, the reason behind trying to use ActiveRecord was the transaction management. It's possible to do the same with:

```
client.query 'BEGIN'
client.query 'COMMIT'
client.query 'ROLLBACK'
```